# Use numpy.frompyfunc to add broadcasting to a python function with argument

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

From an array like `db` (which will be approximately `(1e6, 300)`) and a `mask = [1, 0, 1]` vector, I define the target as a 1 in the first column.

I want to create an `out` vector that consists of ones where the corresponding row in `db` matches the `mask` and `target==1`, and zeros everywhere else.

```
db = np.array([       # out for mask = [1, 0, 1]
# target,  vector     #
  [1,      1, 0, 1],  # 1
  [0,      1, 1, 1],  # 0 (fit to mask but target == 0)
  [0,      0, 1, 0],  # 0
  [1,      1, 0, 1],  # 1
  [0,      1, 1, 0],  # 0
  [1,      0, 0, 0],  # 0
  ])
```

I have defined a `vline` function that applies a `mask` to each array line using `np.array_equal(mask, mask & vector)` to check that vectors 101 and 111 fit the mask, then retains only the indices where `target == 1`.

`out` is initialized to `array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`

```
out = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The `vline` function is defined as:

```
def vline(idx, mask):
    line = db[idx]
    target, vector = line[0], line[1:]
    if np.array_equal(mask, mask & vector):
        if target == 1:
            out[idx] = 1
```

I get the correct result by applying this function line-by-line in a `for` loop:

```
def check_mask(db, out, mask=[1, 0, 1]):
    # idx_db to iterate over db lines without enumerate
    for idx in np.arange(db.shape[0]):
        vline(idx, mask=mask)
    return out

assert check_mask(db, out, [1, 0, 1]) == [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] # it works !
```

Now I want to vectorize `vline` by creating a `ufunc`:

```
ufunc_vline = np.frompyfunc(vline, 2, 1)
out = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ufunc_vline(db, [1, 0, 1])
print out
```

But the `ufunc` complains about broadcasting inputs with those shapes:

```
In [217]:     ufunc_vline(db, [1, 0, 1])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-9008ebeb6aa1> in <module>()
----> 1 ufunc_vline(db, [1, 0, 1])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,4) (3,)
In [218]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting `vline` to a [numpy ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/ufuncs.html) fundamentally doesn't make sense, since ufuncs are always applied to numpy arrays in an elementwise fashion. Because of this, the input arguments must either have the same shape, or must be [broadcastable](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-broadcasting) to the same shape. You are passing two arrays with incompatible shapes to your `ufunc_vline` function (`db.shape == (6, 4)` and `mask.shape == (3,)`), hence the `ValueError` you are seeing.

There are a couple of other issues with `ufunc_vline`:

- `np.frompyfunc(vline, 2, 1)` specifies that `vline` should return a single output argument, whereas `vline` actually returns nothing (but modifies `out` in place).
- You are passing `db` as the first argument to `ufunc_vline`, whereas `vline` expects the first argument to be `idx`, which is used as an index into the rows of `db`.

Also, bear in mind that creating a ufunc from a Python function using `np.frompyfunc` will not yield any noticeable performance benefit over a standard Python `for` loop. To see any serious improvement you would probably need to code the ufunc in a low-level language such as C (see [this example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html) in the documentation).

---

Having said that, your `vline` function can be easily vectorized using standard boolean array operations:

```
def vline_vectorized(db, mask): 
    return db[:, 0] & np.all((mask & db[:, 1:]) == mask, axis=1)
```

For example:

```
db = np.array([       # out for mask = [1, 0, 1]
# target,  vector     #
  [1,      1, 0, 1],  # 1
  [0,      1, 1, 1],  # 0 (fit to mask but target == 0)
  [0,      0, 1, 0],  # 0
  [1,      1, 0, 1],  # 1
  [0,      1, 1, 0],  # 0
  [1,      0, 0, 0],  # 0
  ])

mask = np.array([1, 0, 1])

print(repr(vline_vectorized(db, mask)))
# array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```